# Considering expanding the scope of my question

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I have now realized that all games which use [Steamworks features](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features) (i.e. the majority of modern online games on Steam) potentially download Steam profile images from the same location. My [Counter-Strike: Global Offensive question "How to disable profile images?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319780/how-to-disable-profile-images) could share an answer with hundreds of other Steam games.

Could I simply rewrite the question (using CS:GO as an example) and change the tag to "Steam"? This would also increase the chance of getting a decent answer.

Comment: Timmy's 2nd option is good. Ask a question then answer it. Reference your other question in the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have two options you can do here:

1. Change the question you've already asked as you mentioned
2. Make a new question that focuses entirely on Steam and cite CS:GO or other games as an example

I would be fine with either one of these options you select.  I noticed that you posted your own answer to your post in question. If you edit the post, make sure you update that answer as well (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest editing your question and (if needed) the answer, if the answer already (or almost) answers the expanded question or if there isn't an answer yet,
and asking a new question if the answer only fits the more narrow scope and doesn't fully apply to the expanded question.

Comment: I've come to a conclusion that it is better to create a new Q/A about Steam as the CS:GO information takes so much space (I will reference the question).